# Flex 4 - How to set alternate value for a spark Image control and Spark BitmapImage

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How to set alternate value for *Image* and *BitmapImage* controls in flex 4 like HTML img tag

```
   <img src="url" alt="some_text">
```

But I want to display alternate image if the image is not correct.

Is it possible?

Comment: What you mean "I want to display alternate image if the image is not correct". can you explain in detail?

Comment: I want display an alternate image(not a alternative text), if the source value is wrong i.e if the source url is not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you.

The catch here is `IOErrorEvent`. If images not loading correctly it throws IO_ERROR EVENT (might be incorrect path). Also aware of Cross Domain Security issue.

```
protected function img_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    img.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        img.source = "url";//Make sure it should be Right path;
    });
}

<s:Image id="img" toolTip="Hey tooltip here" creationComplete="img_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />
```

Comment: I think the render event is better than creationComplete event.And we have to add source property in the image component.

Comment: Ya it is ok i think doesn't make much sense. Sometime render event fire multiple times be aware of this issue but even better listen all events at preinitialize event handler.